# File Manager - attach a file

Tags: debian, cinnamon

I am running Debian 10 Cinnamon (among others) and am wondering if there is a way to change the order in the dialog for attaching a file to an email. Currently it is strictly alphabetic and I would prefer to have folders on top (alphabetically) then files (alphabetically). My Mint Cinnamon dialog behaves this way. Knowing how versatile Linux is I presume there must be a way to accomplish this.  Thanks.